# Amazon S3 php class working without credentials

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am going to integrate Amazon S3 bucket service in our Project. I am using PHP class listed here. https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class.

I am using '`putObjectFile`' method in it & it is working fine.

Problem : Now, when I am using this class without passing security credentials.

Like, `$s3 = new S3();`

It is also working perfect, which should not.

So, I don't know, which settings are remaining in bucket. It should only work when I pass perfect credentials.

Here is the my bucket policy

`{
    "Id": "POLICY_ID",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SID_ID",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting the code on a ec2 instance which has a IAM role that gives the ec2 instance full access to the s3 bucket. This allows you to access a bucket without credentials.

From the [AWS documention](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/credentials.html):

> If you do not explicitly provide credentials to the client object and no environment variable credentials are available, the SDK attempts to retrieve instance profile credentials from an Amazon EC2 instance metadata server. These credentials are available only when running on Amazon EC2 instances that have been configured with an IAM role.